# Invert `tidyverse` functions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the follow `df`:

```
set.seed(126)

df <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(2, sample(1:25, 25, replace = TRUE))
)
```

For return distinct values:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df %>% distinct(x.1) %>% count()

# A tibble: 1 x 1
      n
  <int>
1    17
```

But, I want return duplicated values, instead distincts. I try:

```
df %>% !distinct(x.1) %>% count()
```

> Error in distinct(x.1) : object 'x.1' not found

```
df %>% negate(distinct(x.1)) %>% count()
```

> Error: Can't convert a `data.frame` object to function

```
df_1 %>% not(distinct(x.1)) %>% count()
```

> Error in distinct(x.1) : object 'x.1' not found

- I need of a function that invert `tidyverse` functions.

Comment: I don't think there is any general way to "invert" tidyverse functions, at least not without defining what "invert" would mean more generally. In this example though, your desired output can be achieved with `df[duplicated(df$x.1),] `, and the distinct values are given by `df[!duplicated(df$x.1),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df %>%
 filter(duplicated(x.1)) %>%
 count()

      n
  <int>
1    10
```